# Linking directly to a specific point in time of a YouTube video

Tags: youtube, video, links

If I find a video on YouTube that I want to send to a friend, but I really only care about something at the two minute mark, can I send him a link that will start at two minutes into the video for him?

Is there a specific URL or setting when sending a link to a YouTube video that jumps directly to a point in the timeline?

Comment: Related: *[How to share a YouTube video with a specific start and end time?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/61397/60818)*

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Simply add `#t=XhYmZs` to the end of the URL where X is the number of hours, Y is the number of minutes, and Z is the number of seconds.

i.e. `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxxxxx#t=2m0s` for your example.

Comment: Oooh it works: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIMAfwJSfKw#t=46s

Answer (score 15):

You can now right-click inside the video player to copy the URL with the current timestamp.

[image]

Comment: Ooh - that's slick!

Answer (score 5):

Side note: If you are leaving a comment on the video you can't use the full link (Youtube bans all links in comments), but you can use a simple "mm:ss" format in your [comment on Youtube to automatically create a link to that point in the video](http://www.youtube.com/comment?lc=aENl0L4T7bSM38iBJ2oulHYJhp0wiT3ot-B1A7D8c1Y). I haven't seen this documented anywhere but it comes in handy for quick links. Also it uses Javascript instead of the `#t=` anchor so you can make multiple time references and click on them really fast to create quick mash-ups or loop the video at a specific point.

Comment: Seems like it would be possible to use jQuery to replicate this functionality on any website by just-in-time replacing the timestamp (regex match) with the YouTube hyperlink. I may code this myself, but if anyone beats me to it, please let me know and vice versa.