# Are the parameters for www.youtube.com/watch documented?

Tags: youtube

The YouTube watch page can accept a staggeringly high number of parameters, but various Google searches on the topic only resulted in every blogger and their dog announcing the `#t` quasi-parameter for linking to a specific moment.

Is there an at least partial but official documentation on the parameters `www.youtube.com/watch` accepts?

Answer (score 22):

An attempt to provide the basic queries available for YouTube urls.

Usage: [http://www.youtube.com/watch?[Queries]](http://www.youtube.com/watch?%5BQueries%5D)

`v=`

The **v** parameter specifies the `VIDEO_ID`. This field contains an 11-character value that YouTube uses to uniquely identify a video. You can find the video ID for a video in the URL of the web page where you watch that video.

`&list=[LIST_ID]`

The **list** parameter specifies the playlist ID when watching a video from a playlist. Entering the ID of a playlist that this video isn't in results in the second video of the playlist getting played next, except if `index` is given.
There are some special playlist IDs, for example `WL` for the watch later list and `RDMM` for the personal music mix (mixes are a special form of playlists).

`&index=[INDEX_NO]`

The index of the played video in the playlist. Usually causes the video with index+1 getting played next, but there are some special cases when removing videos from the playlist overview on the side or modifying the playlist in other ways while it's being played.

`&fmt=`

The **fmt** parameter specifies the return format for the video resolution
[image]

`&t=`

The **t** parameter allows for [deep-linking](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/732/40) in the form of `#t=1m15s`

`&hl=`

The **hl** parameter prompts the user(host) to a specific the indicated language

Chinese (Traditional)  `&hl=zh-TW`
Czech `&hl=cs-CZ`
Dutch `&hl=nl-NL`
English (Great Britain, Ireland, Australia and New Zealand) `&hl=en-GB`
English (United States and Canada)* default value `&hl=en-US`
French  `&hl=fr-FR`
German  `&hl=de-DE`
Italian `&hl=it-IT`
Japanese `&hl=ja-JP`
Korean  `&hl=ko-KR`
Polish  `&hl=pl-PL`
Portuguese (Brazil) `&hl=pt-BR`
Russian `&hl=ru-RU`
Spanish (Spain) `&hl=es-ES`
Spanish (Mexico) `&hl=es-MX`
Swedish `&hl=sv-SE`

`&gclid=`

The **gclid** parameter is used in auto-tagging for Google Ad Words and will show up in the landing page URL when a user arrives at the page from the ad.

`&lc=`

The **lc** parameter is used to highlight a specific comment as soon as the page is opened. It can be obtained by copying the URL a comment's publishing date (i.e. "2 weeks ago") links to.

`&feature=`

The **feature** parameter is assigned within Youtube to describe certain videos and where display

`&feature=watch_response`

Any videos in response to a video will have this parameter linked to it. (Assigned within youtube)

`&feature=watch_response_rev`

The reverse of the above. The "child" video page will have a link to the "parent" page (Assigned within youtube)

`&feature=pyv`

Promoted Youtube Video (**pyv**) on a watch page  (Must be entered within Google AdWords Editor destination url)

`?feature=pyv`

Promoted Youtube Video (**pyv**) on a channel page (Must be entered within Google AdWords Editor destination url)

`&kw=`

The **kw** parameter is an indication of keyword insertion. Keyword insertion is an advanced feature that can help make an ad more relevant to a diverse audience. Each time the ad shows, AdWords will automatically replace the code with the keyword that triggered the ad. (Must be entered within Google AdWords Editor destination url)

---

**Unfinished section**

`&ad=` Advertisement Id assigned to an advertisement ?
`&feature=recent_shows`
`&feature=recentu`
`&feature=recentlik`  Recently Liked ?
`&feature=spotlight`
`&feature=related`
`&feature=channel`
`&feature=branded`
`&feature=aso`
`&feature=sub`
`&feature=fvw`
`&feature=fvwk`
`&feature=fvhl`
`&feature=BF`
`&feature=topvideos`
`&feature=more_related`
`&feature=list_related`
`&feature=player_embedded`
`&feature=artistob`
`&feature=youtu.be`
`&playnext=[1 or 0]`
`&list=QL`  Queue List ?
`&shuffle=`
`&videos=`
`&playnext_from=`
`&force_ap=`

<sub>Sources  
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/732/40  
http://youtube-global.blogspot.com/2008/10/link-to-best-parts-in-your-videos.html  
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube#Quality_and_codecs  
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#Localized_Category_Lists  
http://www.google.com/support/adwordseditor/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=57752  
http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=74996</sub>

Comment: I like where this is going. :)

Comment: If you are watching a shuffled playlist you will have `index` and `list` parameters. The `index` will be a simple integer. The `list` parameter just points to the playlist itself. The `shuffle` parameter is kind of interesting. It's an integer that somehow encodes the order of the sorted items. But a long playlist could have a huge number of possible sort orders (n! I believe). I believe YouTube uses the `shuffle` parameter in a sorting algorithm. The page breaks with a 500 error if you put a very large number, so they are not sanitizing input on that param. Whoops.

Comment: Does the table of formats mean that only 4K videos on YouTube can have a 48K sample rate? Or does this only apply when manually entering the parameter?

Answer (score 5):

Since Youtube removed the button to show all the videos from an uploader, this might come in useful.

If you use the parameter `&list=UL` you'll get a playlist with all the uploaded videos from that particular channel.

That's very useful when you're watching though older videos, and don't want to have to go to the channel and click "show more" a bunch of times every time you'll want to resume from where you got to.

This way you can bookmark the page and resume from that point later. The parameter `watch?v=[VIDEO_ID]` defines where you've gotten to in the playlist.

Example

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[VIDEO_ID]&list=UL
```

While this works well, it doesn't always show the videos in the "publish" order you see when looking at the channel's video list normally. Often, for example, a series of videos can play in reverse order when using it. This is possibly because `&list=UL` sorts the videos in strict upload order, while many channels upload videos ahead of time and schedule their publish times independently.

Comment: This no longer applies. The "all uploads" playlist now has the same ID as the channel (not the custom URL, but the ID).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `&stereo=0` or `&stereo=1` to define if you want to hear the video in stereo (1) or in mono (0).