# Embed start time in a YouTube video

Tags: youtube, url

I want to give out a link to a YouTube video have it start the playback at a specific time in the clip, e.g., 2 minutes and 45 seconds.

Is that possible?

Comment: Dup: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/732/how-can-i-link-to-a-youtube-video-at-a-specific-point-in-the-video

Comment: @mark4o: go that direction yourself. Embedded parameters have nothing to do with the plain youtube link. Ok? As well as those who as those who ask and answer the questions. It is a dup of http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13607/specific-start-time-with-new-youtube-embedded-code, which was created a month later. And, there is a right answer, http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/13612/15479. Downvote and remove the wrong answer here.

Comment: @Val: This question is about embedding a start time in a YouTube URL to send to someone, not embedding a video with a start time in a web page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To specify a point, append a tag to the end of your video link with the following syntax: `#t=1m45s` (you can change the numbers before the "m" and "s" to edit the minutes and seconds, respectively.

Here's an example:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1bibCui3lFM#t=1m45s

Comment: @Val Dude, watch your language....