# Link to specific point in time on SoundCloud

Tags: links, url, soundcloud

I would like to share a link to a sound file on [SoundCloud](http://soundcloud.com/) that automatically starts playing at a certain point in time. Is this feature available on SoundCloud, and if so, how do the respective URLs look like?

This is basically the same feature as [Linking directly to a specific point in time of a YouTube video](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/732/45128), only for audio instead of video.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you hit the share button on a song, the screen features a check box that lets you create a link to the a specific time:

[image]

It's worth noting that at this stage, you can click the orange timeline above to navigate the song and find the time you're trying to link.

Comment: Correct. FYI it just append #t={hours}:{minutes}:{seconds} to the SoundCloud URL as is mentioned in another answer.

Comment: This does not show up for me (Firefox). I have the blank space there in the share menu pop-up, to the right of the url, but there is no selector, also not when I turn off my ad blocker. Weird because the play seek thing is still above and it totally looks like that would let you select where to link to, but it doesn't, it's just a playback control? Also adding the timestamp manually as suggested by Patrick below does not work: https://soundcloud.com/user-126600832/sets/valve-portal-songs#t=1:22 just starts at the beginning. Something's broken here

Comment: Oh, I just noticed the `/sets/` in the link I previously posted. The soundcloud search results just took me there, I didn't even know this was a thing to look out for. When going to an individual song, it works! So that might be the problem for anyone else who thinks this is missing :)

Answer (score 30):

You can append **`#t={hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}`** to the SoundCloud URL (not including the `{` or `}` characters).

Examples (try to click):

- https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-podcast-51#t=9:36
- https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-podcast-51#t=09:36
- https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-podcast-51#t=00:09:36
- https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-podcast-51#t=01:02:03