# How to share a YouTube video with a specific start and end time?

Tags: youtube

YouTube gives the option to share a video with a specific start time, something like this:

```
http://youtu.be/chElHV99xak?t=53s
```

The above video starts at 53 seconds elapsed.

Is there any way to provide an end time as well, like forming a small clip?

Example: start at 53s and end at 59s.

Comment: All supported parameters can be found here: [YouTube Embedded Players and Player Parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?csw=1#Parameters)

Comment: You can also use [vibby](https://www.vibby.com). It allows you to create a video as a part of a youtube video. You copy the youtube link, select the start and the end time, save it as a New Vib and you can share it. :) It's not youtube-only solution, but it helped me with my requirement, so it might help someone ese too. :)

Comment: As the question is old, answers are no longer permitted.  I have the best answer.  Use this text....   https://www.youtube.com/embed/[ENTER_VIDEO_ID_HERE]?start=00&end=22.  So for example if your Youtube link is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sj9S0EYS5EI, the video ID here will be sj9S0EYS5EI and your link will be https://www.youtube.com/embed/sj9S0EYS5EI?start=00&end=22

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You can use `?start=<seconds>` and `?end=<seconds>` to define start and end points, such as:

- https://www.youtube.com/embed/chElHV99xak?start=53&end=59

This only works with the above (*embed*) style of link (as opposed to the *watch* page).

Note: the time must be an integer number of seconds (e.g. `119`, not `1m59s`).

Comment: Thanks, it worked, though it needed some tweaking. Can you edit your post to make it more elaborate, giving some step wise instructions. it took me sometime to figure out that time here has to be only in seconds.

Comment: can you make it start automatically when clicked on the link ?

Comment: @Devid Add `&autoplay=1` to the url.

Comment: Here's the documentation with all the parameters you can add to the url, although start, end, and autoplay are the most relevant: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters

Comment: Not all videos allow you to share them this way.

Comment: end parameter works only with embed video. If I add `loop` or `autoplay` next to end parameter, the loop or autoplay doesn't work. Is there a way to make loop work?

Comment: @grgarside My mistake. I didn't fully read the answer - I just saw the start and end parameters and skimmed the rest, tried to use it with the standard link, discovered it did not work, figured out the embed solution and thought I was contributing. I've deleted the comment. The request for upvote was not self-promotion but, as explicitly mentioned, only a way around the site's hiding later comments where it wouldn't help someone, as I mistakenly thought it would

Comment: Does not work with certain copyright protected videos. Example: https://www.youtube.com/embed/5x5NCDYB1Lc?start=74&end=78

Comment: I think the solution doesn't work anymore.

Comment: The tip worked for me. This is what I used <iframe allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="409" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/l82OgpqvRok?start=1&amp;end=185" width="400"></iframe> over here - http://mvark.blogspot.com/2019/05/difference-between-stalemate-impasse.html  ...a 4 minute video stops at the 3:05 mark

Comment: This definitely does work.  Using embed is key: https://www.youtube.com/embed/DR5kw8S9l0k?start=33&end=35

Comment: FWIW, this still works for me in a vanilla Chrome session, but it fails when using an autoplay blocker extension. In that case it just starts from the beginning of the video after you click to play.

Comment: Doesn't work. When I try with https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=BgGv92n4SWI?start=53&end=59 , I get "An error occurred. Please try again later."

Comment: @Regjohn1 Your URL is incorrect — `/embed?v=Bg…` should be `/embed/Bg…`. Separately, that video cannot be embedded so the correct embed URL does not work.

Comment: Can confirm this still works for the videos that haven't disabled it (it's enabled by default but can be disabled by video creators on a per-video basis). It even ends the video at the end time as if that's where the video actually ends. There's also a dedicated option for it in YouTube's interface if you click `Share > Embed`, although it only provides an option to copy the HTML, requiring you to still manually build the link if that's all you need.