# How to set start end time for every video on Playlist in YouTube?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist, url

How to set start end time for every video on Playlist in YouTube?

There is alike question asked but for a single video

[YouTube video start end times](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/61397/how-to-share-a-youtube-video-with-a-specific-start-and-end-time)

I can set start and time times in url but playlist is not affected.

[Playlist starts at 1s time, first video at 5s](https://www.youtube.com/embed/SbQc_JLUH7k?autoplay=1&loop=1&start=5&end=8&playlist=96kI8Mp1uOU)

Appending start end times to video from the playlist fails

[Start end times appended to playlist video fail to work](https://www.youtube.com/embed/SbQc_JLUH7k?autoplay=1&loop=1&start=5&end=8&playlist=96kI8Mp1uOU&start=5&end8)

Comment: this cant be done for playlists

Comment: YouTube has a feature called "clips" which lets you share just a clip of a longer video. Unfortunately, you can't add clips to playlists.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible.

It was working like this before [Youtube has officially removed the feature](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/Gipu_cCDScI).

Was also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41046667/playing-several-custom-youtube-video-urls-with-start-and-end-time-in-sequence-li).

Comment: if this feature is not supported for the playlist, it doesn't mean a playlist can not be scripted to get this feature to work as before.
Just write a javascript to play a number of videos in sequence, to make them a playlist

Comment: @darius, I'm glad that you've found a workaround for your issue. However, your question appears to be within Youtube's native playlists, not custom automated implementations. And that's how others would probably read it.
P.S.: Though if you know of any browser extentions featuring start/end times for such custom playlists, please let me know!

Comment: @hypers Please see my answer, I've almost materialized your idea. 'Almost' because the said extension isn't aware of the playlist creature. The intent is to support multiple intervals.