# Is there a way to link to a Netflix movie at specific time?

Tags: netflix

Is there a way to link to a Netflix movie at a specific time, similar to [how you can link to a Youtube video at a specific time](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/732/linking-directly-to-a-specific-point-in-time-of-a-youtube-video)?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

With the HTML5 player, which Netflix serves [on many browsers](https://help.netflix.com/en/node/23742)<sup>1</sup>, it appears that adding a `t` [parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) in seconds will seek to it. For example, to skip to 5 minutes, add `&t=300` at the end of the current URL.  Change the ampersand (`&`) to a question mark (`?`) if the URL doesn't currently have parameters.

For example,

> https://www.netflix.com/watch/70302157

becomes

> https://www.netflix.com/watch/70302157?**t=300**

but

> https://www.netflix.com/watch/70302157?trackId=something&tctx=something

should be

> https://www.netflix.com/watch/70302157?trackId=something&tctx=something&**t=300**

This seems to be an undocumented feature and could probably change or be removed at any time.

<sup><sup>1</sup>As of December 2015, Firefox 43 64-bit on Windows gets the HTML5 player.</sup>

Comment: Hmm... I tried this and it didn't seem to work for me. For example, https://www.netflix.com/watch/80057444?t=600 should jump to the 10 minute mark, but it doesn't seem to. Does it work for you?

Comment: @rampion It worked for me, actually, using Google Chrome.

Comment: Chris Hayes: Hmmm... worked in Chrome for me too. Interestingly, in Firefox I get a 302 redirect from the above URL to http://www.netflix.com/WiPlayer?movieid=80057444 while I get no redirect in Chrome.

Comment: Maybe it's b/c I use Silverlight in Firefox, but Chrome uses HTML5?

Comment: @rampion It would indeed appear to require the html5 video, but I'm not getting a 302 on firefox. `t` just doesn't do anything. I'm guessing the seeking takes place client-side and just wasn't implemented for the silverlight player.