# How to get a link to an exact time in a Microsoft Stream (Classic) video?

Tags: video, office-online, microsoft-stream-classic

Both on YouTube<sup>1</sup> and Google Drive<sup>2</sup>, it is possible to create a link which starts the video at some specific time.

On [Microsoft Stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Stream), when I write some timestamps into the description, after clicking on the timestamp the video moves to the given time. But I wasn't able to find an URL which would direct the browser to start the video at that time.

<sup>1</sup>[Linking directly to a specific point in time of a YouTube video](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/732)

<sup>2</sup>[Google Drive Video Player Start Time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24848779)

Answer (score 2):

## Try ?st=150 URL parameter to jump to 2:30 minutes

When you choose the option [to share a video](https://docs.microsoft.com/stream/portal-share-video), you can choose an option "start at". You can enter the chosen time there.

[image: start at]

After you do so `?st=150` (or some other number corresponding to time in seconds) is appended to the URL.

It is also possible to use et parameter to add the end time, for example, `?st=150&et=180` should play the video from 2:30 to 3:00.

See also:

- [Cut to the chase by sharing your video at a specific point](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-stream-archive/cut-to-the-chase-by-sharing-your-video-at-a-specific-point/ba-p/285094).
- [Start and end points in Stream video embed code](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-stream-forum/start-and-end-points-in-stream-video-embed-code/m-p/1426808)

EDIT: Microsoft announced that they are now launching a new version of Microsoft Stream: [Stream (built on SharePoint), the new version of Microsoft Stream](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/stream/streamnew/new-stream). The description given in this answer is about the version available at the time of posting - which they now call Stream (Classic).

Answer (score 1):

For the new Stream platform (not Stream "Classic"), appending something similar to the following works for me:

```
&nav=%7B%22playbackOptions%22%3A%7B%22startTimeInSeconds%22%3A999%7D%7D
```

Try replacing the `999` with your time in seconds and appending to your existing Sharepoint-Stream URL.

This can be duplicated by clicking on "Share" and "Embed".  Check and adjust the "Start from" value, and then inspect the embed URL code.

If you are curious about the %-encoded terms, decoding them shows this is a JSON payload provided in the URL:

```
&nav={"playbackOptions":{"startTimeInSeconds":999}}
```

Comment: It might be better to post a new question, ... it might be a self-answered question. P.S. There is a site focused on Sharepoint -> [sharepoint.se].